# how to do a sum if another cell contains a certain 'word

Tags: google-docs, google-sheets

I have a sales sheet columns along this format

```
------------------------------------------------
|     A   |      B    |    C       |   D       |   
------------------------------------------------
|  type  |   Cost     | card fee   |    Total  |
------------------------------------------------
| cash   | 10.00      | 0.00       | 10.00     |
------------------------------------------------
| visa   | 10.00      | 0.50       | 10.50     |
------------------------------------------------
```

I currently put the values in B and C manually and then (D) sums the Total

What I want to do is have the cardfee (C) column do the calculate the sum B*5% only if (A) is = 'visa' but if its anything else (C) can be blank or 0.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the IF function =IF ( condition, if_true, otherwise_value )

```
=IF(A2 = "visa", B2*0.05, 0.00)
```